# Trying to link two models using Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a couple models set up, Users and Events. I want Users to be able to add Events to themselves. I may be going about this completely wrong, but what I have so far are these models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class eventItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.event.title

class Event(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank = 'TRUE', primary_key='TRUE')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE')
```

I'm trying to write a view that is activated whenever a User clicks a button next to an event. The result should somehow link the User and the Event together so that I can later look at the list of Events that each User is attending. I think I may also be using the wrong type of field for the eventItem. Since many users can link to the same event and many events can link to one user, should I be using a ManytoMany?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying a bit: You have users and events where each user can have more than one event, and one event can have more than one user. This means that the best approach in this case is to use a ManyToMany, as you suggested in the end. You avoid having the "eventItem", and you directly access (in django) users from events and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks, I read up a little more and changed it to that. Now, how would I handle writing a view that activates when I click a button and adds the event to a user's "eventList"

Comment: In a button, you have two choices: either you use a GET method (using a url), or a POST method (form or javascript). In the view, you should use user.eventList.add(event) after you catch the request.method == "POST" or request.method == "GET", and respective data request.POST/request.GET. Try to see in docs about GET and POST in Django.